# How to install a custom ROM on a generic Chinese Android tablet?

Tags: custom-roms

My generic Chinese Android tablet has Android 5.1 pre-installed on it.
Here is a [link](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/7-Inch-Google-Android-5-1-Quad-Core-Tablet-PC-16GB-Dual-SIM-3G-Unlocked-GPS-HD/172870645024?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) to the eBay page on where I bought it.

How can I install Android 6.0 onto it?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Trouble is less "how can I install", but rather to find one in the first place. Tough luck with that most likely. See: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: As you can see, this is a device without even a brand name or model, so obviously there's no way one can find the kernel source of the device, so no custom ROMs possible. Or maybe you can try porting ROMs of similar device, or you need to dig deep into the Chinese rabbithole forums like this: http://bbs.gfan.com/ to find one.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Chinese tablet but on my tablet I have Android 4.1.1 Jellybean. So first you can see what is the type of the proccesor you have. Next step is to search a custom ROM for your tablet (a CyanogenMod is a good choice). But you need to root your tablet (Superuser is a good choice) and you need to install CWM. You can watch on YouTube step-by-step (you can watch and you will understand)

Comment: Could you provide a link to such a YouTube video?